# What's the 'real' way of saying 'cautiously extends'?

Tags: logic, terminology

Its well known that ZF is equiconsistent with ZFC. Thus we say 'the Axiom of Choice *cautiously* extends ZF'.

Except we don't, because I just made that up. What's the usual way of saying this sort of thing?

Comment: I would just say that ZFC is an equiconsistent extension of ZF. Of course, I'm not a set theorist, so I don't know if they have some special terms for that.

Comment: Speaking as a set theorist, we would say that the axiom of choice is *relatively consistent* with ZF.

Comment: @MihaHabič, doesn't that mean that ZF is equiconsistent with C, rather than meaning that ZF is equiconsistent with ZFC?

Comment: As a strict interpretation I suppose so, however, it is common to suppress the implied base theory. When reading "a principle A is relatively consistent with a theory T", one should interpret this as "if T is consistent then A+T is consistent", giving an equiconsistency result.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the equiconsistency of a theory $T + \phi$ relative to $T$ says, for theories that include or interpret arithmetic, that if $T + \phi$ proves $0=1$ then $T$ proves $0=1$.

We can broaden this notation in a certain way. Let $C$ be a set of formulas. We say that a theory $T'$ is *conservative* over a theory $T$ for formulas in $C$ if, for all $\phi \in C$, if $T'$ proves $C$ then $T$ proves $C$. In this case $T'$ is no stronger, with respect to formulas in $C$, than $T$ already was. If $T \subseteq T'$ we say $T'$ is a *conservative extension* for formulas in $C$.

Equiconsistency is thus a very weak form of conservativity. It is common in practice to establish much stronger conservation results. For example, one consequence of Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem is that

> ZFC is conservative over ZF for all sentences in the language of Peano
>   arithmetic (or, strictly speaking, the interpretations of these sentences into
>   the the language of set theory).

One such sentence is $0 =1$, but this conservation result is much stronger than that. Fermat's last theorem, the Riemann hypothesis, and other interesting results can be phrased as sentences of Peano arithmetic. Thus, if ZFC proves these, they are already provable in ZF.